# Why is event NOT waiting on callback to finish?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I cannot get the following event to await the result of ActionShared.BL.Managers.TaskManager.GetTask - it just continues - and the TaskDetailsPageViewController is never shown. Please advice if you can see the bug ??

```
public async void OnButtonPressedTask (object sender, CellUtilityButtonClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.UtilityButtonIndex == 1){
        // Edit
        var a =  GetItem(e.IndexPath) as Outstanding;
        APTask  ab = new APTask();
        ab.Id = Convert.ToInt32(a.Entity.Id);
        await ActionShared.BL.Managers.TaskManager.GetTask  (ab.Id, async (response) => {
                var taskDetailsPage = new TaskDetailsPageViewController(response, e.IndexPath);
                parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(taskDetailsPage, true);  
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you wanting it to wait? You have the await call on the task that is returned from `GetTask`, but there isn't anything after it. Are you wanting the code inside of the lambda to be awaited?

Comment: Eclipsed4utoo yes its the code inside the lambda I want to be awaited ?

Comment: Probably because nothing in your task is being awaited. As soon as PushViewController is called it continues onward. There is nothing that tells it to wait for PushViewController to be finished before continuing.

Comment: In addition to @AndresCastro, PushViewController isn't awaitable.

Comment: Wrap the PushViewController call inside a try{}catch{} and you will most likely see a UI thread exception. You would need to invoke that call in the UI thread (in iOS: parent.InvokeOnMainThread(() => parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys
I changed ActionShared.BL.Managers.TaskManager.GetTask to use async/await in stead of a call back.